# Automatically remove entry from Firebase that is out of date

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, server, firebase-realtime-database

I have an iOS social app that uses Firebase as the main database to store all the posts with time stamp included

What I want to achieve is to remove anything that is > 10 days old from my database.

Currently, I am checking this with this super inefficient way (The only way I know). Every time the user queries the firebase, I have swift code that also queries the ENTIRE database and delete all entries that is > 10 days old. This works but it is really inefficient...

Comment: If your posts is separate into children of root. You can index and query it. No need to load entirely

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do is currently best done on a server you control with a job that runs periodically to scan and delete the old items.  You can use the [admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup) for that.

You should also have a index on the time field that you're using to determine how old it is, in order to optimize the query that generates the results.